# Запаздывает выделение отредактированной ячейки в angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

В [UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) пытаюсь сделать выделение отредактированной ячейки синим цветом. Для этого в `afterCellEdit` обрабатываю изменение и вношу соответствующие пометки в сущность, а в `cellClass` проверяю эти пометки в сущности и возвращаю соответствующий класс. Вызов `$scope.$apply` (который показан в документации) есть.

Следующий пример упрощённый: в нём исключена проверка столбца. В реальности она у меня есть и подсвечивается только одна нужная ячейка в строке. Но проблема видна и в этом варианте:

1. Выбрать ячейку в столбце Company (но не в нижней строке).
2. Изменить значение.
3. Нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   Значение изменится, в колонке Edited отобразится true, курсор переместится в следующую строку. **Но текст останется чёрным.**
4. Нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   Текст в отредактированной на шага 2 ячейке станет синим.

**Как сделать, чтобы текст синел на шаге 3, а не 4?**

http://plnkr.co/edit/SEEf4DPhA3CB1mx7R4I8?p=preview

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'edited',
      enableCellEdit: false
    },{
      field: 'company',
      cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
        return row.entity.edited ? 'blue' : '';
      }
    }],
    
    onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
      gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function (rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
          rowEntity.edited = true;
          $scope.$apply();
        }
      });
    }
  };

  $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
    });
}]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav class="grid"></div>
```

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/39204053/4928642)

Comment: _Вызов $scope.$apply (который показан в документации) есть._ - добавь ссылку на это. Пока видно только, что это событие выполняется после _cssClass_ - поэтому и не применяется ничего, так как во время выполнения cssClass - флаг еще не выставлен

Comment: @Grundy, да, событие вызывается позже, а apply не вызывает повторное выяснение классов. Я это уже выяснил, ожидал, что из текста вопроса ясно :) По поводу документации и apply - код тут: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable. Не думаю, что это важно для вопроса.

Comment: а вот это видел? :-) https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3449

Comment: и советуют вот: [notifydatachange](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi#methods_notifydatachange)

Comment: @Grundy, не пойму, как его правильно вызвать...

Comment: Добавил ответ :-)

Comment: @Grundy, а я как раз разобрался :)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39204053/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как указано в [соответствующем тикете](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/3449) на гитхабе - значение *cssClass* не отслеживается, поэтому на него никак не влияет вызов `$scope.apply()`

Вместо этого рекомендуют указать гриду, что была изменена колонка с помощью [метода notifyDataChange](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.core.api:PublicApi#methods_notifydatachange)

В итоге будет вот так:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'uiGridConstants',
  function($scope, $http, uiGridConstants) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableCellEditOnFocus: true,

      columnDefs: [{
        field: 'edited',
        enableCellEdit: false
      }, {
        field: 'company',
        cellClass: function(grid, row, col, rowRenderIndex, colRenderIndex) {
          return row.entity.edited ? 'blue' : '';
        }
      }],

      onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
          if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            rowEntity.edited = true;
            gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN);
          }
        });
      }
    };

    $http.get('https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/gh-pages/data/100.json')
      .success(function(data) {
        $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
      });
  }
]);
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}
.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav class="grid"></div>
```

Comment: _"значение cssClass не отслеживается"_ - там вообще `cellClass` не вызывается. На английском тоже ответишь, или мне самому?

Comment: Кстати, я `uiGridConstants.dataChange.EDIT` использовал.

Comment: можешь сам, _значение cssClass не отслеживается_ - я имел ввиду что на них watch Нет, поэтому и не вызывается при изменении. И как я понял что-то с EDIT у них там не получалось и в примере было COLUMN :)

Comment: У них не получилось `gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(gridApi.grid, uiGridConstants.dataChange.EDIT);` из-за лишнего первого параметра - вместо строки в качестве действия приходил сам грид :)